# lisp filter out results from list not matching predicate

Tags: list, lisp, filter, elisp, predicate

I am trying to learn lisp, using emacs dialect and I have a question.
let us say list has some members, for which predicate evaluates to false.  how do I create a new list without those members?  something like `{ A in L: p(A) is true }`. in python there is filter function, is there something equivalent in lisp?  if not, how do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

These functions are in the CL package, you will need to `(require 'cl)` to use them:

```
(remove-if-not #'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

This will return a new list with all even numbers from the argument.

Also look up `delete-if-not`, which does the same, but modifies its argument list.

Comment: I would like to point out that the function `#'remove-if-not` are deprecated in Common Lisp[¹](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_removecm__elete-if-not.html) where the filter would be written `(remove-if (complement #'evenp) '(1 2 3 4 5))` or simply `(remove-if #'oddp '(1 2 3 4 5))` — the function `complement` does not exist in Emacs Lisp to my knowledge though.

Comment: Pls use *cl-lib* package, and use **cl-remove-if-not** function as replacement.

Comment: The gigamonkeys book claims that "If the standard is ever revised, it's more likely the deprecation will be removed than the -IF-NOT functions."

Answer (score 25):

If you manipulate lists heavily in your code, please use [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) modern functional programming library, instead of writing boilerplate code and reinventing the wheel. It has every function to work with lists, trees, function application and flow control you can ever imagine. To keep all elements that match a predicate and remove others you need [`-filter`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/blob/master/README.md#-filter-pred-list):

```
(-filter (lambda (x) (> x 2)) '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; (3 4 5)
```

Other functions of interest include [`-remove`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/blob/master/README.md#-remove-pred-list), [`-take-while`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/blob/master/README.md#-take-while-pred-list), [`-drop-while`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/blob/master/README.md#-drop-while-pred-list):

```
(-remove (lambda (x) (> x 2)) '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; (1 2)    
(-take-while (lambda (x) (< x 3)) '(1 2 3 2 1)) ; (1 2)
(-drop-while (lambda (x) (< x 3)) '(1 2 3 2 1)) ; (3 2 1)
```

What is great about `dash.el` is that it supports [anaphoric macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro). Anaphoric macros behave like functions, but they allow special syntax to make code more concise. Instead of providing an [anonymous function](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lambda-Expressions.html) as an argument, just write an [s-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) and use `it` instead of a local variable, like `x` in the previous examples. Corresponding anaphoric macros start with 2 dashes instead of one:

```
(--filter (> it 2) '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; (3 4 5)
(--remove (> it 2) '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; (1 2)
(--take-while (< it 3) '(1 2 3 2 1)) ; (1 2)
(--drop-while (< it 3) '(1 2 3 2 1)) ; (3 2 1)
```

Answer (score 19):

I was looking for the very same last night and came across the [Elisp Cookbook](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook) on [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/). [The section on Lists/Sequences](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc39) contains filtering teqniques and show how this can be done with `mapcar` and `delq`. I had to mod the code to use it for my own purposes but here is the original:

```
;; Emacs Lisp doesn’t come with a ‘filter’ function to keep elements that satisfy 
;; a conditional and excise the elements that do not satisfy it. One can use ‘mapcar’ 
;; to iterate over a list with a conditional, and then use ‘delq’ to remove the ‘nil’  
;; values.

   (defun my-filter (condp lst)
     (delq nil
           (mapcar (lambda (x) (and (funcall condp x) x)) lst)))

;; Therefore

  (my-filter 'identity my-list)

;; is equivalent to

  (delq nil my-list)

;; For example:

  (let ((num-list '(1 'a 2 "nil" 3 nil 4)))
    (my-filter 'numberp num-list))   ==> (1 2 3 4)

;; Actually the package cl-seq contains the functions remove-if and remove-if-not. 
;; The latter can be used instead of my-filter.
```

Answer (score 7):

Emacs now comes with the library `seq.el`, use `seq-remove`.

```
seq-remove (pred sequence) 
"Return a list of all the elements for which (PRED element) is nil in SEQUENCE."
```

Answer (score 1):

With common lisp, you can implement the function as follows:

```
(defun my-filter  (f args)
    (cond ((null args) nil)
        ((if (funcall f (car args))
            (cons (car args) (my-filter  f (cdr args)))
            (my-filter  f (cdr args))))))

(print 
      (my-filter #'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of ways to filter or select stuff from a list using built-ins which are much faster than loops.  The built-in remove-if can be used this way.  For example, suppose I want to drop the elements 3 through 10 in list MyList. Execute the following code as an example:

```
(let ((MyList (number-sequence 0 9))
      (Index -1)
      )
  (remove-if #'(lambda (Elt)
                  (setq Index (1+ Index))
                  (and (>= Index 3) (<= Index 5))
                  )
              MyList
           )
 )
```

You will get '(0 1 2 6 7 8 9).

Suppose you want to keep only elements between 3 and 5.  You basically flip the condition I wrote above in the predicate.

```
(let ((MyList (number-sequence 0 9))
      (Index -1)
      )
  (remove-if #'(lambda (Elt)
                   (setq Index (1+ Index))
                   (or (< Index 3) (> Index 5))
                  )
              MyList
           )
 )
```

You will get '(3 4 5)

You can use whatever you need for the predicate that you must supply to remove-if.  The only limit is your imagination about what to use. You can use the sequence filtering functions, but you don't need them.

Alternatively, you could also use mapcar or mapcar* to loop over a list using some function that turns specific entries to nil and the use (remove-if nil ...) to drop nils.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in basic elisp you can type something like

(mapcan (lambda(x) (and (zerop (% x 2)) (list x))) '(1 2 3))

This will return (2).

To play this trick you need to have a t/nil returning function that represents your filtering condition. It exploits mapcan usage of nconc, and the fact that both

(nconc '(a) nil)

and

(nconc nil '(a))

return

(a)

Answer (score 0):

It's surprising there's no builtin version of filter without `cl` or (or `seq` which is very new).

The implementation of `filter` mentioned here (which you see in the Elisp Cookbook and elsewhere) is incorrect. It uses `nil` as a marker for items to be removed, which means if you have `nil`s in your list to start with, they're going to be removed even if they satisfy the predicate.

To correct this implementation, the `nil` markers need to be replaced with an uninterred symbol (ie. gensym).

```
(defun my-filter (pred list)
  (let ((DELMARKER (make-symbol "DEL")))
    (delq
      DELMARKER
      (mapcar (lambda (x) (if (funcall pred x) x DELMARKER))
              list))))
```