# How to get file list by extension?

Tags: elisp

I want to get a list of all files with specific extension in a directory, and then pass it as an argument. How to do it in ELisp?

Comment: I don't understand "and then pass it as an argument".  Could you please edit the question to clarify what sort of output you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you do not need any extra filtering.  `directory-files` does ***everything*** you want, i.e., including the filtering to match the extension (e.g. `ext`):

```
(directory-files DIRECTORY nil "\\.ext$")
```

See `C-h f directory-files`.  For the current directory, you can use:

```
(directory-files default-directory nil "\\.ext$")
```

Comment: `directory-files-recursively` for all the files matching the extension in this folder and all subfolders.

Answer (score 2):

`directory-files` retrieves all the files in a directory as a list.  `remove-if-not` removes list entries not matching a predicate.

```
(require 'cl)
(remove-if-not (lambda (filename) (eq "ext" (file-name-extension filename)))
               (directory-files dir) )
```

(I'd love to avoid the `(require 'cl)` there.  http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc38 has some hints.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2235401/874188 has a non-CL equivalent.  `(delq nil (mapcar (lambda (filename) (if (eq "ext" (file-name-extension filename)) filename nil)) (directory-files dir)))`

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is to use [`f`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) library every time I work with files and filepaths in Elisp. Here you need [`f-files`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-files-path-optional-fn-recursive) to get a list of files in a directory and [`f-ext`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-ext-path) to extract an extension from the filename. [`-filter`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-filter-pred-list) is a `remove-if-not` equivalent from [`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list manipulation library. The expression you need is thus:

```
(-filter (lambda (x) (equal (f-ext x) "ext")) (f-files "dir"))
```

With [anaphoric macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) we can make even more terse expression by removing `lambda` (convention is to use 2 dashes for anaphoric versions):

```
(--filter (equal (f-ext it) "ext") (f-files "dir"))
```

But `f-files` accepts a custom function that already filters the list of files, so why not discard `-filter`?

```
(f-files "dir" (lambda (x) (equal (f-ext x) "ext")))
(f--files "dir" (equal (f-ext x) "ext")) ; anaphoric version
```