# What would be a good or efficient way to get the list of alphabet used in a string

Tags: string, common-lisp

#### Put it simply, how to get a list non-repeated letters from a string in Common Lisp?

e.g:

```
"common"
-> ("c" "o" "m" "n") or in characters, (#\c #\o #\m #\n)
I'd care less about the order and type, if it is in string or character.

"overflow" -> (o v e r f l w)
"tomtomtom" -> (t o m)
   etc...
```

What I was thinking is to collect the first *letter* of the original *string*,
Then use the function;

```
(remove letter string)
```

collect the first *letter* of now, *removed letter string* and append it to the already collected letters from before.
It sounds like recursion but if recursively calling would loose the previously collected *letter*s list, right? I also doubt if there is any built-in functions for this.

Furthermore, I don't want to use *set* or any of them since I want
to do this completely in functional style.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CL-USER> (remove-duplicates (coerce "common" 'list))
(#\c #\m #\o #\n)
```

Or you can even do it simply as:

```
CL-USER> (remove-duplicates "common")
"comn"
```

Comment: wow, googled a lot and never came, across `remove-duplicates` function. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There may be certain better possibilities to do that, if you can make some assumptions about the text you are dealing with. For instance, if you are dealing with English text *only*, then you could implement a very simple hash function (basically, use a bit vector 128 elements long), so that you wouldn't need to even use a hash-table (which is a more complex structure). The code below illustrates the idea.

```
(defun string-alphabet (input)
  (loop with cache =
       (coerce (make-array 128
                           :element-type 'bit
                           :initial-element 0) 'bit-vector)
     with result = (list input)
     with head = result
     for char across input
     for code = (char-code char) do
       (when (= (aref cache code) 0)
         (setf (aref cache code) 1
               (cdr head) (list char)
               head (cdr head)))
     finally (return (cdr result))))

(string-alphabet "overflow")
;; (#\o #\v #\e #\r #\f #\l #\w)
```

Coercing to `bit-vector` isn't really important, but it is easier for debugging (the printed form is more compact) and some implementation may actually optimize it to contain only so many integers that the platform needs to represent so many bits, i.e. in the case of 128 bits length, on a 64 bit platform, it could be as short as 2 or 3 integers long.

Or, you could've also done it like this, using integers:

```
(defun string-alphabet (input)
  (loop with cache = (ash 1 128)
     with result = (list input)
     with head = result
     for char across input
     for code = (char-code char) do
       (unless (logbitp code cache)
         (setf cache (logior cache (ash 1 code))
               (cdr head) (list char)
               head (cdr head)))
     finally (return (cdr result))))
```

but in this case you would be, in your worst case, create 128 big integers, which is not so expensive after all, but the bit-vector might do better. However, this might give you a hint, for the situation, when you can assume that, for example, only letters of English alphabet are used (in which case it would be possible to use an integer shorter then machine memory word).

Answer (score -5):

Here some code in Haskell, because I am not so familiar with Lisp, but as they're both functional, I don't think, it will be a problem for translating it:

```
doit :: String -> String

doit [] = []
doit (x:xs) = [x] ++ doit (filter (\y -> x /= y) xs)
```

So what does it? You've got a String, if it's an empty String (in Haskell [] == ""), you return an `empty` String.
Otherwise, take the first `element` and concatenate it to the recursion over the `tail` of the String, but `filter` out those elements, which are == `first element`.

This Function `filter` is only syntactic sugar for a specific `map-function`, in Lisp called `remove-if` as you can reread here: [lisp filter out results from list not matching predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234860/lisp-filter-out-results-from-list-not-matching-predicate)

Comment: @wvxvw What makes you think it has quadratic memory usage?

Comment: @wvxvw Actually, it will create only one list (of the elements that pass through all previously created filters), due to laziness. But even with eager evaluation, there would only ever be one list alive at a time, so the memory usage would be linear [of course the total allocations would be quadratic, unless there are enough repeats].

Comment: @wvxvw Maximum needed at any one time. Though total allocations is sometimes an interesting measure too, it's not what is meant with memory complexity. Yes, for the problem at hand, this is not a good algorithm. It is, however, not particularly bad in terms of memory usage (though one could also improve that).