# Filter function in Elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, higher-order-functions, remove-if

Is there equivalent of higher-order function `filter` in Emacs Lisp? Like function from python or Javascript.

```
(filter-equivalent (lambda (n) (= (% n 2) 0)) '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))

==> (2 4 6 8)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [lisp filter out results from list not matching predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234860/lisp-filter-out-results-from-list-not-matching-predicate)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's `cl-remove-if-not`. A bit of a mouthful, but it works.

To elaborate a bit, you need

```
(require 'cl-lib)
```

to get this function. There's an alias for it, called `remove-if-not`, but
I prefer not to use it, since it may look like I'm using `remove-if-not` from `cl`.

It's a good practice to include the prefix, not doing `using namespace std` in C++,
but saying `std::cout` each time.

Comment: In Emacs 23, there seems to be a `remove-if` and `remove-if-not` not in the cl compatibility package.

Comment: @Vatine Emacs 24 have `remove-if` and `remove-if-not` too, you should post it as answer because those are built in.

Comment: @Vatine, @jbubic: The `remove-if-not` in Emacs 23 is part of its CL compatibility features, it's defined in `cl-seq.el`. It is always available without the need to `require` anything, though, at least in my experience. Maybe in older Emacs versions, `cl-seq.el` wasn't loaded by the default configuration?

Comment: It's not autoloaded in Emacs 24, you have to require `cl-lib`.

Answer (score 11):

The third-party [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) library provides a `-filter` function as an alternative to `cl-remove-if-not`.

```
(-filter 'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))

;; => (2 4 6 8)
```

Comment: dash.el is really a must-have library for serious Emacs Lisp programming :)