# LISP list Clisp function smaller than

Tags: lisp

I want to write a function that takes two arguments 
an atom `x` and a list `L` and returns a list of numbers in list `L` that are smaller than `x`

like for example:

List is `(2   10   3  9   4   8)`  and `x` is `5`

Output should be: `(2 3 4)`

I guess i can use the less than function

```
(defun less-than (x y)
  (or (< x y))
```

but it returns less than from the list :(

Comment: What is your code to filter the list? Have you seen `(remove-if inverted-pred list)`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234860/lisp-filter-out-results-from-list-not-matching-predicate

Comment: @reto Don't have to invert since you have `remove-if-not`

Comment: @Sylwester But inverting the predicate is so easy: `(remove-if (complement #'pred) ...)` :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Nice that it's more than one way to skin a cat :)

Comment: @Sylwester Well, according to [the spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm), "The :test-not argument is deprecated. The functions delete-if-not and remove-if-not are deprecated."  I've heard lots of people say that's silly, and they keep on using them.  I think the argument in favor for deprecation, though, was the availability of `complement`.  I don't really hesitate to use `*-if-not` and `:test-not`, myself.

Comment: @reto Have **you** seen `(remove-if-not uninverted-pred list)`? Wink.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun less-than (x L)
  (remove-if-not
   (lambda (e) (< e x))
   L))

(less-than 5 '(2 10 3 9 4 8))
=> (2 3 4)
```

or

```
(defun less-than (x L)
  (remove-if
   (lambda (e) (>= e x))
   L))
```

Comment: Because `remove-if-not` works with general sequences, the answer also works with vectors. `(less-than 5 #(2 10 3 9 4 8))`.